# Spontaneous reboots of system

Tags: memory, cpu, temperature

I have an older desktop (i7-920, 2.66 GHz) which I built a number of years ago but have noticed that it now spontaneously reboots (with differing error messages).

This is a secondary machine with my main one being a laptop, this one's just used because of the space and also as a place to host a share of development VMs.

This is not the fault of the OS as any flavour of Windows will exhibit these symptoms; the only variant of Linux I tried to install refused to do so and just hung midway. I've paved the system on about a half-dozen occasions now and still the issue persists.

I'm trying to isolate what it is could be causing the issue so I'm running MemTest86+ on it as I type this on another machine. The first thing I notice is (according to MemTest) is that the CPU is running between 70°C and 75°C. According to this page [here](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7-920%20AT80601000741AA%20(BX80601920%20-%20BXC80601920).html) the temperature range for this processor is 5°C-67.9°C

Could this be causing the reboots? Is there likely some damage done to the processor already and am I as well not trusting it anymore?

Comment: Post the error messages.

Comment: Sorry, they're many and various with no common thread discernable between them. The last OS I tried to install on it was Windows 10 Preview and off the top of my head there was an NTFS error and a IRQ less than or equal to error but nothing that constantly recurred

Comment: A mostly idle CPU should not be running at 70°C. Check your cooling.

Comment: Reboots due to overheating are not uncommon...definitely check that first. Also, Windows 10 Preview is not a good OS to be running as your primary as it's still quite unstable and picky with drivers.

Comment: Sounds like your machine has been eating dust. Dust accumulation over the years is an all time favorite for overheating problems with aging systems. Open up your tower and give everything a good clean out.

Comment: @NathanC I just installed W10 preview because nothing else would install :-/

Comment: My current desktop (for games and VMs) is also a core i7-920. Idle temps in a 22°C room are 33-36°C.  Your idle temp is way too hot. Check cooling as SBI suggested.

Comment: @SBI I took your suggestion and stripped the system down completely, including removing and cleaning the CPU heat sink (and re-applying thermal paste). I used a pump for blowing up airbeds along with a vacuum cleaner. Isopropyl alcohol removed the old thermal paste.  I'm now running at 38 - 42°C across all cores.

Comment: @noonand Glad to hear you're up and running again. Turned my comment into an answer to give this question a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your machine for dust. Dust is a fantastic thermal insulator and also keeps fans from running as well as they should, and is therfor one of the most common reasons of machines overheating. This is especially, but not only, true for systems with either limited airflow or limited space, such as small form towers or laptops. Depending on the environment you run your computer in, it will accumulate a lot of dust over time.

Open up your machine and clean everything that seems overly dusty. Places that are especially prone to collecting dust are fans and heatsinks, such as on your graphics card or on your CPU. Carefully remove large amounts of dust and see if your machine goes back to running with normal temperatures.